# Command zip2john is not working

Tags: linux

I'm just running a test. There is a zip on my desktop, and the password is "12345".

I already installed John the Ripper on Ubuntu 19.04. This is what I am doing (terminal opened on the desktop):

```
zip2john test.zip > hash.txt
```

The output:

```
zip2john: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if the binary of zip2john ist in the current folder, start it with `./zip2john`. Otherwise add the path of zip2john to the environment `"$PATH"` variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
git clone "https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper.git" && cd JohnTheRipper/src && ./configure && sudo make -s clean && sudo make -sj4
```

Then go run and try `./zip2john`.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is not up-to-date and official. Here is copied from the official documentation:

```
git clone https://github.com/openwall/john -b bleeding-jumbo john
cd john/src/
./configure
make -s clean && make -sj4
```

To use the tools like `zip2john`, you can navigate to the `run/` folder:

```
cd ../run/
./zip2john test.zip
```

Just an usage example.

Answer (score 6):

Adding another way to use `zip2john`:

It is included in the [Snap version of John the Ripper](https://snapcraft.io/john-the-ripper) tested on Ubuntu 20.04.

To install John:

```
snap install john-the-ripper
```

After installing, use `john-the-ripper.zip2john` in the command line, for example:

```
john-the-ripper.zip2john test.zip > hash
```

Source: [Reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/kkh9ii/zip2john_and_another_2john_commands_arent_being/)