# John the ripper 'zip2john' Command not found Mac

Tags: macos, zip

When I try to crack zip file it always shows -bash: zip2john: command not found.
I installed through homebrew, run john shows no error, I'm not sure is the command not installed or what?
When I run ls /bin/ I do not see zip2john command.
I tried solutions listed [Command zip2john is not working](https://superuser.com/questions/1457837/command-zip2john-is-not-working) but still not working. New to these staff. HELP T_T (Device: Mac Big Sur)

Answer (score 5):

My mac is also Big Sur M1.

If you install john and use brew, the brew install john-jumbo command `zip2john` will be in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/john-jumbo/1.9.0/share/john/zip2john` on the path.

Because, john only links to `/opt/homebrew/bin/`
So I can't find it

Maybe you can add `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/john-jumbo/1.9.0/share/john/`
to $PATH ,then it can be used normally

```
ryan.chen@ryanMac bin % ls -al | grep "john"
lrwxr-xr-x    1 ryan.chen  admin     35 Aug 18 11:05 john -> ../Cellar/john-jumbo/1.9.0/bin/john

ryan.chen@ryanMac john % ./zip2john 
Usage: ./zip2john [options] [zip file(s)]
Options for 'old' PKZIP encrypted files only:
 -a <filename>   This is a 'known' ASCII file. This can be faster, IF all
    files are larger, and you KNOW that at least one of them starts out as
    'pure' ASCII data.
 -o <filename>   Only use this file from the .zip file.
 -c This will create a 'checksum only' hash.  If there are many encrypted
    files in the .zip file, then this may be an option, and there will be
    enough data that false possitives will not be seen.  If the .zip is 2
    byte checksums, and there are 3 or more of them, then we have 48 bits
    knowledge, which 'may' be enough to crack the password, without having
    to force the user to have the .zip file present.
 -m Use "file magic" as known-plain if applicable. This can be faster but
    not 100% safe in all situations.
 -2 Force 2 byte checksum computation.

NOTE: By default it is assumed that all files in each archive have the same
password. If that's not the case, the produced hash may be uncrackable.
To avoid this, use -o option to pick a file at a time.
ryan.chen@ryanMac john % pwd
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/john-jumbo/1.9.0/share/john
```

Comment: I found the `zip2john` executable, and it is sym-linked to the `john` executable

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the full version of John
`brew install john-jumbo`

Answer (score 0):

on my M1 Mac, `zip2john` is sym-linked to `john`,
but in a location that is not where the `john` executable is - so it is not in the `PATH`

Comment: That won't make zip2john not found. Both commands would work when symlinked.